# SQL : .NET vs SSMS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I've been struggling this problem for two days now. I've rewrote the code and the statement, but ended up with the same result.

My goal is to be able to get the full name from the suppliers list, that has a similar buyer name from a different table. The code I used:

```
SELECT BuyerID, SupName 
FROM Buyers b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN suppliers s ON s.supname LIKE RTRIM(b.BuyerName) + '%'
```

I've also tried this code as well

```
SELECT b.BuyerID, b.BuyerName, s.SupName 
FROM Buyers b, suppliers s 
WHERE PATINDEX(RTRIM(b.BuyerName) + '%', s.supname) <> 0
```

My expected output should look like this, It produce the same result from Microsoft SQL Server Management Suite, as shown below.

```
BuyerID | BuyerName | Supname
--------+-----------+---------------------
AA      | Alfrac    | Alfrac Insurance.
BC      | Bank      | Bank of America
CC      | Charle    | Charles Dawnson
```

My WPF output result like this.

```
BuyerID | BuyerName | Supname
--------+-----------+---------------------
AA      | Alfrac    | Null
BC      | Bank      | Null
CC      | Charle    | Charles Dawnson
```

In WPF, this is the code I used:

```
string sql = ReadEmbeddedResource("Queries.GetBuyerSupplier.sql");
DataSet Data = new DataSet();
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqldb"].ConnectionString)))
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(Data);
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

In the Queries.GetBuyerSupplier.sql is the SQL command above.

Here's the list of things I've tried:

1. Google
2. SET ARITHABORT ON
3. option(recompile)
4. Common Table Expression
5. Declare and using Temp Table
6. Change login credentials (Using SQL vs Domain Authentication)

Version of the tools that I'm using:

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4019093) - 12.0.5207.0 (X64)   Jul  3 2017 02:25:44  Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

SQL client driver:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client v 10.50.1617.0

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 V 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 
Microsoft .NET Framework V 4.7.02558
OS: Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Can you add your `WPF` class code...maybe you have the wrong datatype and the convertions fails somehow.

Comment: Done, nothing fancy about that. Just a datasetadapter fills into DataSet.

Comment: WPF output suggest that it result of first query. You have left join there, so it is possible that you will get null in Supname when join codition "s.supname like RTRIM( b.BuyerName ) + '%'" is not fulfilled. This queries are not equivalent of each other - first will return columns with null(and more rows) for data which dooesn't fulfill condition.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on this line `cmd.Connection.Close();` and inspect the content of your `Dataset`...if the values are there, then we can continue with.

Comment: Same result. I'm beginning to suspect that it has to do with driver issues, How WPF and SSMS talks to the engine is beyond me at this point.

Comment: have you tried putting  the sql in a string directli? string sql = "SELECT ...". Maybe you're using an old file?

Comment: @Isitar - The file is only loading from the embedded resources, It changes everytime when I either make changes to the files. I have verify that there isn't any other obsolete/old files laying around ( Each time VS compiles, it compiles on top of whatever left in the directory. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. As it turns out, the other set of the code was a recursion of CTE (Initially the code was feed into a comma splice, then I had a CTE recursion to split the strings into rows, then later feed into the code above. Once I set the CTE recursion result into temp table, I finally went back and update the table with the correct suppliers and now they all appears to be working correctly.

What I did to fix this was first append the buyer code into a temp table, once the recursion was finish, I then do a update on the supname afterward using the LEFT OUTER JOIN comparison.

Just wondering why my driver didn't let the recursion finish before comparing the result? It seems to be a bit broken there, seeing how it only return one of the many unfinished result back. SSMS did the proper job of waiting for the recursion to finish before returning the results.

It's a driver issue at this point. Thank you guys for your help.